# Ain't able to send email to facebook as a message from my PHP webservice

Tags: php, ios, facebook, html-email

I am trying to send an email to some facebook account (example: my_username@facebook.com) via my PHP (core) web service. But, I am not able to receive the mail as a message in my facebook acccount. However, I am able to receive the mail through my gmail account.

As far as I know, we can check whether the mail is getting sent through my PHP script, but not it's successful delivery.
I have developed my webservice to interact between an Iphone app (with updated SDK for iOS 7) and my web server.

Now my questions are :

1. Do I need some specific headers or do I require some SMTP settings to sent mail to user's facebook message account?
2. Do I need to do something with the Iphone app?
3. Can I get the user's primary email address (which the user has used to signup on facebook) instead of my_username@facebook.com in Iphone app?

Precisely, do I need some change in my PHP script or in my Iphone app?
 
Please help me with your suggestions.

Thanks...!!!

Comment: We can't know if you need to change your code unless you show us some of the code you already have.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your script. 99% certain it is a spam-filter at facebook that catches your email. PHP sent email using just the mail() function more often than not gets caught in spam filters.

There is a big rant (With usefull info on solutions) on the horror of sending email [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html)

Comment: I am using the following code :

<?php

$to = "example@email.com";
$body = "some@mail.com";
$subject = "Demo subject";

$headers  = "From: my_email@domain.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: my_email@domain.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
    
$sendMail = mail($to,$subject,$body,$headers);
  
if($sendMail == 1) {
   // some code
} else {
   // some code
}

?>

Comment: Still, it's not working. I checked my code again and again for spam, but, the message to the facebook user is not getting deliver. I have specified my code in my previous comment. Any help would be appreciated.